# Detect capslock state in ElectronJS

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using `iohook` to manage keyboard input, but it cannot detect whether capslock key is on or off, neither electron `globalShortcut`.

Any idea? Can use another library if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BrowserWindow and not just the Tray, you may try the following -

```
let wc = mainWindow.webContents; //where mainWindow = new BrowserWindow

wc.on('before-input-event', (e, i) => {

  if(i.key === 'CapsLock') {
     if(i.type === 'keyUp') {
        console.log('Caps: OFF');
     } else {
        console.log('Caps: ON');
     }
  }
});
```

keydown is observed to be the type for CapsLock = ON and keyup for CapsLock = OFF